# Getting error on CASE statement, incorrect syntax near ","

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've looked up the CASE syntax for similar scenarios and other issues people have had and can't find this one specifically.  This is giving me a syntax error near the comma after the first case statement and I can't figure out why.

```
insert into usmas_Doors_HardwarePrepCodes(HWTypeMask, PrepTypeMask)  
select  
(  
    CASE HWType  
        WHEN NULL THEN 0  
        WHEN 'BT' THEN 1  
        WHEN 'CL' THEN 2  
        WHEN 'DB' THEN 3  
        WHEN 'ED' THEN 4  
        WHEN 'FB' THEN 5  
        WHEN 'HG' THEN 6  
        WHEN 'LK' THEN 7  
        WHEN 'SK' THEN 8  
        WHEN 'VW' THEN 9 END,

    CASE 
        WHEN PrepType IS NULL AND Cutout = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN PrepType = 'A' AND Cutout = 0 THEN 1
        WHEN PrepType = 'H' AND Cutout = 0 THEN 2
        WHEN PrepType = 'L' AND Cutout = 0 THEN 4
        WHEN PrepType IS NULL AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1024
        WHEN PrepType = 'A' AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1025
        WHEN PrepType = 'H' AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1026
        WHEN PrepType = 'L' AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1028 END
)
from HardwarePrepCodes
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:  Have tried "END AS [ColumnName]" and that just throws syntax error near AS

Comment: remove the `(` and the `)`

Comment: That worked... although I'm not sure why

Comment: don't use AS just END [column name alias]

Comment: It worked because "syntax of sql"  does not include `(` and `)` around field list. Now are you sure why?

Comment: It is not proper syntax to do `SELECT (column1, column2...) FROM` You can't encapsulate multiple columns in parenthesis like that.

Comment: Yeah I understand now Hogan.  Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, my work here is done.  (* Drops query on floor and leaves stage. *)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is happening because you have both case statements enclosed in parentheses. Everything enclosed inside (both case statements) would get returned as a single column.

Simply removing them will fix the problem.

```
insert into usmas_Doors_HardwarePrepCodes(HWTypeMask, PrepTypeMask)  
select   
    CASE HWType  
        WHEN NULL THEN 0  
        WHEN 'BT' THEN 1  
        WHEN 'CL' THEN 2  
        WHEN 'DB' THEN 3  
        WHEN 'ED' THEN 4  
        WHEN 'FB' THEN 5  
        WHEN 'HG' THEN 6  
        WHEN 'LK' THEN 7  
        WHEN 'SK' THEN 8  
        WHEN 'VW' THEN 9 END,

    CASE 
        WHEN PrepType IS NULL AND Cutout = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN PrepType = 'A' AND Cutout = 0 THEN 1
        WHEN PrepType = 'H' AND Cutout = 0 THEN 2
        WHEN PrepType = 'L' AND Cutout = 0 THEN 4
        WHEN PrepType IS NULL AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1024
        WHEN PrepType = 'A' AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1025
        WHEN PrepType = 'H' AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1026
        WHEN PrepType = 'L' AND Cutout = 1 THEN 1028 END
from HardwarePrepCodes
```

Comment: Ahhh that's why.  I didn't know parentheses worked like that.  Thanks man

Comment: @JohnJanke It looks like I got beat by a bunch of comments on your original question haha. But yes, it's not just case statements that work like that with parentheses. You would get the same error if you had done something like `select (col1, col2) as mycol from table`, since you're basically saying "both col1 and col2 should independently be in this column".